# how to write a function to add the integer of corresponding letter in python?

Tags: python

how to write a function to add the integer of corresponding letter in python?

for example:

```
   L=[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5),('a',2),('c',2),('b',1)]
```

How to solve it by just loop over the item in L?

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

I guess the clearest way is just to loop through and add them up.

```
>>> L=[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5),('a',2),('c',2),('b',1)]
>>> import collections
>>> d=collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for key,n in L:
...   d[key] += n
... 
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 7)]
```

Comment: Would probably prefer `collection.Counter` since it also offers `counter.most_common()` for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary for it and add the repeated key values , Just like that.

```
dict = {}
for i in L:
  if i[0] in dict: 
        dict[i[0]] += i[1]
  else:
        dict[i[0]] = i[1]
dict.items()
```

Output will be : [('a', 5), ('c', 7), ('b', 5)]

Answer (score 0):

you can try to define a function like this :

```
def sorting(L):

    dit = {}
    result = []
    for l in L :
        dit[l[0]]= 0


    for key , item in dit.items():
        for ll in L :
              if key == ll[0] :
                  dit[key] += ll[1]


    for key , item in dit.items():
        result.append((key , item))

    return sorted(result)
```

you will see the result :

```
>>> sorting(L)  

[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 7)]
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's the obligatory one-line itertools solution:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [
...    (k, sum(g[1] for g in group))
...    for k, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(L), key=lambda x: x[0])
... ]
[('a', 5), ('b', 5), ('c', 7)]
```

Comment: @thg: I posted before I tested, and made a mistake I was apparently penalized for. And the `key=lambda x: x[0]` _is_ needed. You get `[(('a', 2), 2), (('a', 3), 3), (('b', 1), 1), (('b', 4), 4), (('c', 2), 2), (('c', 5), 5)]` without it

Comment: First you sort it, then you group it calling lambda for each element, then you iterate over it again to take sums, plus it will take minutes to figure out what's happening here later on. And there is a standard way of doing this.

Comment: @bereal: Pretty sure the iteration is lazy here and it only iterates once (in addition to the initial sorting).